# How do I unset a value in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to unset a value from a multi-dimensional array when an user presses a button. The array looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [1726]=>
  array(2) {
    [1736]=>
    int(1)
    [1737]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [2314] =>
  array(2) {
    [1436]=>
    int(3)
    [1567]=>
    int(4)
    [2457]=>
    int(7)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to unset for example

```
$_SESSION['cart'][1][1]
```

What Ï've tried so far:

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'add':
        $_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id]++;
        var_dump($_SESSION['cart']); exit();
        break;
    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id]--;
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id]);
    break;
    case 'delete':
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you want to unset for example `$_SESSION['cart'][1][1]`, use for example `unset($_SESSION['cart'][1][1])`.

Comment: The question is unclear. Your code should work just fine. Isn't it? If not, what have you tried so far? Where you think the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 $_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id] = '';
 unset($_SESSION['cart'][$deb_id][$product_id]);
```

Comment: What is the point of adding your first line? It's totally useless.

Comment: making sure of deletion? I'm also new to this